# PHP - Download a file and record the download as a Google Analytics event

Tags: php, post, curl, google-analytics, download

I have some PHP code to that allows a customer to download a file (specifically, an Excel add-in) from my server by clicking a link in an email.  Before the download is initiated, however, I want to record the download as an event in Google Analytics, which requires a POST to **google-analytics.com.**  Here is a excerpt:

```
<?
//log download in Google Analytics
$url = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect';
$fields = array(
                                'v' => 1,
                                'tid' => 'UA-12345-1',
                                'cid' => '555',
                                't' => 'event',
                                'ec' => 'email',
                                'ea' => 'foo'
                                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

//initiate download
$filename = '/path/to/some/file.xlam';
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");       
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
readfile($f);
exit;
?>
```

Although file.xlam appears to download properly with this code, it is somehow corrupted during this process.  The indications that the file is corrupt are that

1. Excel says so
2. when I right-click the file and select Properties and then Details tab, there are no details.

If I remove the **CURL code** (up to `curl_close()`) and just do the download portion, everything works fine.  I suspect this has something to do with **"headers already sent,"** but not sure.  Is there a workaround here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that adding the CURLOPT_HEADER to 0 has helped.

ie. add the following line before your CURLOPT_URL line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
```

This stops headers being returned by the CURL statement.